# android null pointer exception in Application

Tags: java, android

i have an activity which initialize a variable of my Application class (AppVariables):

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    app = (AppVariables) getApplicationContext();
}
```

when using this if condition which check if a drawable is null or not i get a null pointer exception from some reason:

```
    if (app.getFacebookCurrentUser().getProfilePicture() != null)
```

can't really under stand why.. i am checking if it null..

Comment: getFacebookCurrentUser could be null

Comment: ohhhhh stupid me.. i should have check that app.getFacebookCurrentUser doesn't return null...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry guys, it was silly question but at least lets learn from it..
i should have check that app.getFacebookCurrentUser() isn't null.
the right condition is:

if (app.getFacebookCurrentUser() != null && app.getFacebookCurrentUser().getProfilePicture() != null)

Answer (score 0):

You get the exception because `app.getFacebookCurrentUser()` has returned null.  Check it like this:

```
if (app.getFacebookCurrentUser() != null && app.getFacebookCurrentUser().getProfilePicture() != null)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are checking, whether getProfilePicture() is null or not.
What if, app or current facebook user returned by  getFacebookCurrentUser() is null ?

calling a method on any one of them can cause a NULL pointer exception.